# Promise.all() return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, es6-promise

I have have array with three pet names. One is incorrect. Target is to fetch pets from api and if pet not exist to return altered array with only existing pet names. Problem is that Promise.all() return undefined.

```
const getValidPets = async (pets) => {
    const petsArray = pets.map(async (pet) => {
      try {
        const record = await getPetHttp(pet);
        return record.name;
      } catch (error) {
        return undefined;
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(petsArray).then((filteredPets) => {
      const arr = filteredPets.filter(petName => petName !== undefined);
      return arr; // ["Rex", "Jug"] - here is correct!
    });
};

const pets = ["Rex", "Jug", "some_wrong_name"];
const finalPets = await getValidPets(pets); // undefined - incorrect
```

Comment: Your array is an array of `strings` and not not an array of `Promises`

Comment: My target - get promise of all pets, return their (valid) names as string array

Comment: Your code works fine as is: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYNbKP?editors=0012 . You must be missing something or not logging the right value at the end.

Comment: @Paulpro I have change code function getPetHttp ( name ) {
  return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
      return resolve( 'Jug' );
  } );
} and   const record = await getPetHttp(pet);
        return record; and I get ["Jug", "Jug", "Jug"]

Comment: @TeodorKolev Resolve with `name` instead of always 'Jug'.

Comment: It should resolve with an object `{ name }` so that when you access `record.name` you get the string. If you just resolve with a string then you will get all undefined, because `'Jug'.name === undefined`.

Comment: Your code works fine with a mock HTTP function: http://jsfiddle.net/srqv7pob/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - as has already been said, your example code works so long as `getHttp(pet)` is mocked or equivalent.

Comment: @Paulpro please add this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const getValidPets = async (pets) => {
    const petsArray = pets.map(pet => getPetHttp(pet).then(record => record.name).catch(() => undefined));

    return Promise.all(petsArray).then((filteredPets) => {
        const arr = filteredPets.filter(petName => petName !== undefined);
        return arr; // ["Rex", "Jug"] - here is correct!
    });
};

const pets = ["Rex", "Jug", "some_wrong_name"];
const finalPets = await getValidPets(pets); // undefined - incorrect
```

Comment: I need try catch, because it will crash on invalid pet

Comment: Crash meaning rejecting the promise returned by `getPetHttp`?  The `catch` part should handle that.

Comment: @Jaime `Array.prototype.map` method do requests procedurally and `Promise.all` should take care to do this in a concurrent way.

Comment: @TeodorKolev Is all this code wrapped in an `async` function right? `await` is only valid in async function.

Comment: Yes, bottom 2 lines are in async function